# OpenLDAP+Kerberos authentication – id (NSS) works, but authentication says user is unknown

Tags: authentication, ubuntu-12.04, openldap, kerberos

I have a central authentication server with OpenLDAP set up and populated, and Kerberos 5, also populated.

On an Ubuntu LTS machine, I set up nslcd and kerberos client stuff. This way, issuing the

```
id gergely.polonkai
```

tells me I'm `gergely.polonkai(10000)` in group `engineering(10000)`. Also, issuing

```
kinit gergely.polonkai
```

asks for my password, and creates my keychain (klist shows my TGT).

Thus, I assume every bit works fine. But when I add kerberos stuff to pam:

```
auth sufficient pam_krb5.so
account sufficient pam_krb5.so
session optional pam_krb5.so
```

the logs say gergely.polonkai authenticated successfully, then says gergely.polonkai is unknown to the underlying authentication module.

**Edit**:

```
getent passwd gergely.polonkai
```

gets me the correct data. However

```
getent shadow gergely.polonkai
```

tells me nothing (trying both as root).

**Edit**:

adding shadowAccount objectClass to the user fixed the shadow problem. However, the original error still persists.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The first thing I would try is a more straightforward username that is 8 chars or less. If that works try a longer username that is just a-z. It may be that the pam modules are not handling the username correctly. '.' is a special char that needs quoting in earlier versions of kerberos and it may be causing problems in the pam module code.

Comment: My packages are recent (kinda. it’s a CentOS 6.4). The answer was a bit more obvious; see my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that I was missing something fundamental. After messing up my whole PAM and NSS configuration by hand, I reinstalled the machine (it was a fresh install before my messing). After installing all the necessary packages I did before, running one single magic command by hand did the trick:

```
pam-auth-update
```

As soon as I get back to that machine tomorrow, I will post the resulting pam.d files.